# How do you add multiple events OnClick on an IHTMLElement?

Tags: delphi, interface, mshtml

I am using `MSHTML_TLB` unit.

I used to cast a `IHTMLElement` interface to `IEventTarget` which was supported like one month ago. Then, I would use the method `addEventListener` to add another `OnClick` event.

Now, it doesn't work. It says that it cannot convert the `IHTMLElement` to the `IEventTarget` because the **interface is not supported**. It is the same `HTML` element that was used one month ago.

I changed the code a week ago by importing the `MSHTML` unit, so I use two units which are `MSHTML and MSHTML_TLB`.

**So before the changes, it looked like that:**

```
uses MSHTML_TLB;

{...}

procedure {...}
var
  MyHTMLElement: IHTMLElement;
  EventHandler: IEventTarget;
begin
  { ... some code here }
  { It uses the object IEventTarget from the unit MSHTML_TLB by default }

  if (Supports(MyHTMLElement, IEventTarget, EventHandler)) then
    EventHandler.AddEventListener(...);
end;
```

**Now it looks like this:**

```
uses MSHTML, MSHTML_TLB;

{...}

procedure {...}
var
  MyHTMLElement: MSHTML_TLB.IHTMLElement;
  EventHandler: MSHTML_TLB.IEventTarget;
begin
  { ... some code here }
  { I have to specify that I use a IEventTarget from MSHTML_TLB by default because otherwise, it will take the IEventTarget from the MSHTML unit. }

  if (Supports(MyHTMLElement, MSHTML_TLB.IEventTarget, EventHandler)) then
    EventHandler.AddEventListener(...);
end;
```

My code works fine until it tries to convert the `IHTMLElement` to an `IEventTarget` element and it says that the interface is not supported, so the method "Supports" here return false.

I'm thinking that this maybe caused by importing the `MSHTML` unit, but if so, why? I cannot remove the `MSHTML` unit because I really need it for something else.

Comment: You should only need one import unit, not two.  What is the "something else" that you need MSHTML for?

Comment: It's a long story but I really need the MSHTML AND the MSHTML_TLB. Because if I don't import the MSHTML there are some features that won't work otherwise. And no I cannot make them work with MSHTML_TLB...

Comment: Well, if you don't explain what you are doing which creates the need for both units, I doubt whether readers will be motivated to look into what you're asking.

Comment: I have just imported a old project of mine and it works on my old project. So I replaced my unit from the *new project* with the unit from my old project and it still doesn't work. Now I really don't understand! The old project works, it can cast to IEventTarget. But the *new* project, which has the same unit of the *old* project, so it contains EXACTLY the same code, and it doesn't work.

Now this is something very wierd. It only imports one unit which is MSHTML_TLB. Contains the same code from the old project and it doesn't work. What the hell?